# Multiplying certain elements within an array

Tags: python

I am coding an nth term of a mathematical sequence generator. I'm just experimenting with the first seven terms for now.

The user enters `1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7` (or any other consecutive values) into the sequence, then the program should multiply the 1st, then every other term entered by 8 (so in this case the 1st, 3rd, 5th and 7th numbers entered).

It should also multiply the 2nd then every other term entered by 2 (so in this case the 2nd, 4th and 6th numbers entered).

Afterwards, I want it to add everything together. Here is what I tried to do:

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for n in range (0,7):  
    x[n] = int(input("Input the digits of the sequence one by one:"))
    if x[n] == x[0] or x[2] or x[4] or x[6]:
        x[n] == x[n]*8 

    elif x[n] == x[1] or x[3] or x[5]:
        x[n] == x[n]*2 

    else:
        break

finalnumber = x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4]+x[5]+x[6]
print(finalnumber)
```

I inputted `1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7` and calculated myself that the `finalnumber` should be `152`, however this program for some reason printed `28`.

Please tell me what I have done wrong.

I am using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

You error derives mainly from the way you put the conditions inside your loop -

```
if x[n] == x[0] or x[2] or x[4] or x[6]
```

will check if `x[n] == x[0]` (which might be true even if `n` is not `0`) **or** if `x[2]` is positive (regardless of `x[n]`) **or** if `x[4]` is positive and so on.

- Note that the `or` separates between expressions, and is not used as in english, where `a is b or c or d` implies `a is b, or a is c, or a is d`, but `a is b, or c is true, or d is true`.

The correct way for comparing against multiple value is `if n in [0, 2, 4, 6]` that checks weather `n` is one of the values in that list.

However, for your case, where you want to filter odd and even numbers, there is no need for hard-coding numbers; just make the parity check - `if x % 2 == 0` to cover all cases.

---

Now, lets review your specifications again:

- Input `n` numbers.
- Multiply odd indexes by 2.
- Multiply even indexes by 8.
- Sum it all.

Now python style:

```
n = 7
my_numbers = []

# Input n numbers.
for i in range(n):
    my_numbers.append(int(input("Enter the {} term: ".format(i))))


for i in range(n):
    # Mutiply even indexes by 8.
    if i % 2 == 0:
        my_numbers[i] = my_numbers[i] * 8
    # Mutiply odd indexes by 2.
    else:
        my_numbers[i] = my_numbers[i] * 2

print(sum(my_numbers)) # Sum it all.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `x[n] == x[n]*8`
You should write

```
x[n] = x[n]*8
```

Because double equalmark returns a bool, True or False, it depends on result as mentioned in comments it is used typically with **if** statements, single equalmark means assigning.
Of course the same situation happens when you want to multiply by 2 in second statement.
I meant:

```
x[n] = x[n]*2
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because of this: "double equalmark means checking whether something is equal". The operator `==` returns a bool, `True` if the values are equal and `False` if they are not. It is typically used in `if-statements` and conditionals. Although your answer may help (?) the OP, I think you should rethink your explanation completely, because it is no correct, unfortunately

Comment: I will change this explanation. Thanks for opinion.

Comment: Glad you understand! I just commented on that because I wanted to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you, I did that, but I am now instead getting 212. When I print each element individually, I see that the 4th (x[3]) and 6th (x[5]) values being inputted are being multiplied by 8 even though I specified in the code that they should be multiplied by 2. Why is this?

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Although, this is not the most pythonic way of doing this but there are two major errors with your code.

- Firstly, inside the `if` conditions, you need to check for each of the  values. So, replace `x[n] == x[0] or x[2] or x[4] or x[6]:` with `if (x[n] == x[0]) or (x[n] == x[2]) or (x[n] == x[4]) or (x[n] == x[6]):`
- Secondly, you need to use the `assignment operator ( = )` instead of using `comparison operator ( == )` inside condition blocks. So, replace `x[n] == x[n]*2` with `x[n] = x[n]*2`

The reason you were getting `28` as the result because `x[n] = int(input("Input the digits of the sequence one by one:"))` will assign values to x as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] and in your if-else blocks, there is no assignment of any kind. So, `x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4]+x[5]+x[6]` will result in `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7` which is equal to `28`.

You can do something like this :

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for n in range (0,7):  
    x[n] = int(input("Input the digits of the sequence one by one:"))
    if (x[n] == x[0]) or (x[n] == x[2]) or (x[n] == x[4]) or (x[n] == x[6]):
        x[n] = x[n]*8 

    elif (x[n] == x[1]) or (x[n] == x[3]) or (x[n] == x[5]):
        x[n] = x[n]*2 

    else:
        break

finalnumber = x[0]+x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4]+x[5]+x[6]
print(finalnumber)
```

This will result in :

```
152
```

Alternatively, if you want to do this a bit pythonic way, you can do something like this :

```
x = [int(input("Input the digits of the sequence one by one : ")) for _ in range(7)]
finalnumber = sum([num * 8 if i % 2 == 0 else num * 2 for i, num in enumerate(x)])
print(finalnumber)
```

This will also result in :

```
152
```